# What are good Journals to publish a simple proof regarding an old number theory algebra type proof?

Tags: number-theory

I have seen algebra and number theory which seems reasonable.
I have a half page proof and clearly make my case but I am not the most exacting describer of details.

I am certain that any professional can see my logic and understand my proof and believe its true.  However if one journal has a reputation for being more picky regarding form that probably isn't the one for me.

The proof is so simple that I am not going to mention which subject its regarding for fear that one of you can write it up fast enough to submit :)

I have no immediate access to academia to proof read my proof unless I go back to my old school professors.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: One approach might be to submit it to ArXiV, and then post it here (this way no one can "steal" it if that is your concern).

Comment: Arxiv requires a recommendation to join I believe.  Based on it being very short and an old problem I would prefer to see it in print.  The first one is special.  Its not a major topic but to me it would be my first and possibly only chance to be published.

Comment: Work on writing it down well. There is no point in a bad expositionof simple results.

Comment: "I clearly make my case but I am not the most exacting describer of details." Really? What makes you think, if you cannot describe the details with total clarity and precision, that you do *have* a proof that actually works?

Answer (score 1):

Putting something on the arXiv is a great idea, it will be very helpful in establishing priority if that becomes an issue.

As to where you might try to get published, do you have an advisor or mentor that you trust that you can get advice from? Why not send a quick email to your old school professors? If not, asking here (after staking arXiv ground, if you like) may be appropriate as in the comments.

However, not to discourage you, but if the result really is so simple that you suspect anyone given a hint as to what it is about would be able to reproduce it, this would be quite difficult to get published anyway.

Edit: To clarify, putting something on arXiv does not preclude you from publishing in a print journal later. So what I'm suggesting is that you put it on arXiv, solicit comments directing people there, and then decide what to do based on that feedback.